# Is it possible to make this menu to be vertical?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found a jQuery Dropdown menu on the web , but the problem is that it is horizontal , my project is using a vertical menu. Here are codes :

HTML code :

```js
    $(function() {

      $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function() {

        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');

      }, function() {

        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

      });

      $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

    });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #303030;
}
#page-wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
p {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
/*
     LEVEL ONE
     */

ul.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown li {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  zoom: 1;
  background: #000 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
ul.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
ul.dropdown a:active {
  color: #ffa500;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
ul.dropdown li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
}
/* Doesn't work in IE */

ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover {
  background: #0070C0;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.dropdown li.hover a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*
     LEVEL TWO
     */

ul.dropdown ul {
  width: 220px;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #909090 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
  color: #000;
  float: none;
}
/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */

ul.dropdown ul li a {
  border-right: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
/*
     LEVEL THREE
     */

ul.dropdown ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Simply Styled jQuery Dropdown</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdownPlain.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">For Facilities</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Indoor</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Netting</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Padding</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Training &amp; Conditioning</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ladders &amp; Sticks</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hurdles</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Training Accessories</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Smart-Cart Training System</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Smart-Hurdle Collection</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Books-Videos</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li><a href="#">Field Design</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Training</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The images used in the CSS are just vertical lines like a pipe , the overlay.png image is longer than overlay2.png .

So is it possible to make the menu to be vertical ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change two things

### replace `ul.dropdown li` with bellow

```
ul.dropdown li {
font-weight: bold;
width: 200px;
zoom: 1;
background: #000 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;   
margin:1px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

### replace `ul.dropdown ul` with bellow

```
ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 220px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left:210px;
}
```

### bellow is DEMO

```js
$(function(){

    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function(){

        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

    }, function(){

        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });

    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color:#303030;
} 
#page-wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

p {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

/*
 LEVEL ONE
 */
ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown li {
font-weight: bold;
width: 200px;
zoom: 1;
background: #000 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;   
margin:1px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

ul.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown a:active {
    color: #ffa500;
}

ul.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

ul.dropdown li:last-child a {
    border-right: none;
}
 /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover {
    background: #0070C0;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    color:#fff;
}

ul.dropdown li.hover a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/*
 LEVEL TWO
 */
ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 220px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left:210px;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #909090 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
    color: #000;
    float: none;
}

/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*
 LEVEL THREE
 */
ul.dropdown ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">           
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">For Facilities</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Training &amp; Conditioning</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Ladders &amp; Sticks</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Hurdles</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training Accessories</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Smart-Cart Training System</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Smart-Hurdle Collection</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Books-Videos</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Field Design</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
```

Comment: @pheromix but you didn't mention in question ..where you need gap??

Comment: @sanojlawrence: I thik it's more "the submenu opens on a new line, not starting directly level with the selected top item"

Comment: I don't need gap ! when I run your code snippet then the submenu is situated on the baseline of the parent menu

Comment: @pheromix so you need gap between parent menu and child menu?/

Comment: Nooooo ! it's not what I want ! I don't need gap ! I need the submenu to be at same Y coordinate as its parent menu !

Comment: Nice solution, but as he said it just need to be fixed a little more.(y)

Comment: @chsdk thanks but when i give top margin there are some problem margin submenu

Comment: @sanojlawrence Yes indeed you are right, I fixed it too, see the EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS float, an element can be pushed to the left or right, allowing other elements to wrap around it.

In your CSS remove the `FLOAT` and insert a element width.

replace this section `ul.dropdown li {}` with below

```
ul.dropdown li {
   font-weight: bold;
    /* float: left; */
    width:250px;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #000 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;   
    margin:1px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

You can read up on it *[here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)*.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `float:left` and give at a `width`. You could change it this code:

```css
ul.dropdown li {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #000 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;   
    margin:1px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

To

```css
ul.dropdown li {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 200px;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #000 url(../img/overlay2.png) repeat-x top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;   
    margin:1px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well based in [sanoj lawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3836908/sanoj-lawrence)'s answer, you just need to add these properties to your `ul .dropdown ul` CSS:

```
    margin-top:-24px;   // to make the dropdown aligned with its li element.
    margin-left:-9px;   // to remove the gap between the dropdown and the li element
```

[Here's a **DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rw32ntxa/1/).

**Edit:**

To fix the submenu issue pointed out by [sanoj lawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3836908/sanoj-lawrence) in a comment:

Just add these propreties to the css of the submenu `ul.dropdown ul ul` :

```
margin-top:-1px;
margin-left:1px;
```

And [this is the **new fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rw32ntxa/4/).

Comment: yes ! submenu is displayed at same line as its parent menu :)

Comment: Yes, that was the missing part of it!